# Python index error for hangman game program

Tags: python, string

This is a piece of the program for a game of hangman. I am trying to iterate through the hangman word and print the letter guessed by the user if it matches at that index. If it does not it will print an underscore. I am getting the following error for the second if condition: IndexError: string index out of range

```
while(guessTracker >= 0):
     letterGuess= input("Enter a letter for your guess: ")
     count=0
     wordGuess=""

  if letterGuess in hangmanWord:
     while count<= len(hangmanWord):
        if hangmanWord[count]==letterGuess: 
            wordGuess= wordGuess+ letterGuess
            right= right+1
        else:
            wordGuess= wordGuess + "_ "

        count+=1
    print(wordGuess)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python (and most other programming languages) string indexes start at 0 so the last position is `len(hangmanWord)-1`.

You can fix it just by changing `<=` to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while count<= len(hangmanWord)-1:
```

Because the string's length will never reach the real length (for example: if the word is "hangman", it has a length of 7, but the count starts from 0, and goes up to a maximum of 6, therefor not being able to ever reach the 7th char.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are 0-based so you index a string from index `0` up to `len(hangmanWord) - 1`.

`hangmanWord[len(hangmanWord)]` will always raise an `IndexError`.

You should also give a look to the `enumerate` function that can help with that.

```
wordGuess = ["_"] * len(hangmanWord)

for index, letter in enumerate(hangmanWord):
    if letterGuess == letter:
        wordGuess[index] = letter

print("".join(wordGuess))
```

Answer (score 0):

String indexes are from `0` to `len(string)-1`;
you just need to change your loop like this:

```
while count < len(hangmanWord):
```